# Infix to prefix conversion in Python

Tags: python, prefix, infix-notation

I wanted to make an infix to prefix converter. When I ran the code, the operator in the string sends all the operators in the beginning of the returning string.

How can I fix the code below?

```
class Stack:
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = []
    def isEmpty(self):
        return self.a == []
    def push(self,i):
        self.a.append(i)
    def pop(self):
        return self.a.pop()
    def peek(self):
        return self.a[len(self.a)-1]

def infixToPrefix(s):
    prec = {'/':3,'*':3,'+':2,'-':2,'^':4,'(':1}
    opStack = Stack()

    prefixList = []
    temp = []
    for token in s:
        if token in "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ" or token in "0123456789":
            prefixList.append(token)
        elif token == '(':
            opStack.push(token)
        elif token == ')':
            topToken = opStack.pop()
            while topToken != '(':
                temp.append(topToken)
                topToken = opStack.pop()
            prefixList = temp + prefixList
            temp = []
        else:
            while (not opStack.isEmpty()) and \
                  (prec[opStack.peek()]>= prec[token]):
                temp.append(opStack.pop())
            prefixList = temp + prefixList
            temp = []
            opStack.push(token)
    while not opStack.isEmpty():
        temp.append(opStack.pop())
    prefixList = temp + prefixList
    return ''.join(prefixList)
print infixToPrefix("(A+B)*C-(D-E)*(F+G)")
```

Comment: place your code rather than other site

Comment: Your code is invalid. The last line `while...` is syntactically incorrect.

Comment: Is the expected output: `-*+ABC*-DE+FG` ? Have you tried putting some `print` statements into your `Stack` methods and strategic places through your loop so you can follow what's going on? Have you tried running through your algorithm by hand, with pencil & paper, to make sure it does what you expect it to?

Comment: I should also mention that your digit tokenizing needs fixing, unless you are only feeding single digit numbers to the program.

Comment: I am only feeding single digit numbers in this case

Answer (score 1):

Don't reinvent the wheel. Use a parser generator instead. For example, [PLY](http://www.dabeaz.com/ply/ply.html) (Python `lex`-`yacc`) is a good option. You can start by looking at a [basic example](https://github.com/dabeaz/ply/blob/master/example/calc/calc.py) and either do the conversion within the production rules themselves, or produce an abstract syntax tree equipped with flattening methods that return prefix, infix, or postfix notation. Note that the difference between these three is whether the operator is inserted in pre-, in between, or post-order during a depth-first traversal of the syntax tree (implemented either as a single function or recursively -- the latter leads to simpler and more modular code).

Comment: One hand-crafted solution can be found [here](https://github.com/jsudlow/Infix-to-Prefix-Generic-Expression-Converter).

Answer (score 1):

It might be late to post this answer, but I'm also leaving this as a reference for anyone else. It seems OP, that you already solved the issue when converting from infix to postfix. If that's the case, you can use that same algorithm and code to convert your text to a prefix notation.

All you'd need to do is invert your text first, and then pass that text through your algorithm. Once you invert your text, you'll also store your text in your Stack already inverted. After you've processed this, you need to re-invert your text again to it's original form and you'll get your prefix notation.

Be sure to keep track of what you compare in your dictionary though, you'll no longer compare your operands with the "(".

Hope this helps.